# How to use @UiHandler with customized handler (pass constructor args)

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

Normally, we do this:

```
@UiHandler("aLink")
void onClickALink(ClickEvent e) {
    // do something
}
```

But, what if I want to use my own Handler implementation?

```
class MyClickHandler implements ClickHandler {
    int i;

    MyClickHandler(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then, how do I use MyClickHandler with @UiHandler? i.e. pass `i` to the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create also a specific click event:

```
class MyClickHandler implements ClickHandler {
    int i;

    MyClickHandler(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(MyClickEvent event) {  // MyClickEvent!
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
@UiHandler("aLink")
void onClickALink(MyClickEvent e) {
    // do something
}
```

Make sure you implement all needed methods in `MyClickEvent` so that GWT can understand that it is associated to `MyClickHandler`: see [ClickEvent dispatch(), getAssociatedType() and getType()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ClickEvent.html)

For an example see how [`CustomEvent`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/uibinder/test/client/CustomEvent.java) is implemented in [`HandlerDemo.java`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/uibinder/test/client/HandlerDemo.java).

> Then, how do I use MyClickHandler with @UiHandler? i.e. pass i to the constructor?

You don't.

Comment: Great example. I see what you mean. But are you suggesting that I should pass parameter `i` to the `MyClickEvent` instead of the `MyClickHandler`?

Comment: You have to pass `i` somehow differently, not in the handler. You can just assign it as member variable, but the Handler is not the one who should handle variables.

Comment: I agree, handler should not care about `i`